# What kind of leaf does Totoro carry in My Neighbor Totoro?

Tags: my-neighbor-totoro

It looks to me like a banana leaf, but I have not been able to confirm this. Side question: I've seen it said that he uses it as a "hat" - is this the official interpretation? I've always thought it was used as an umbrella.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a Giant Butterbur to me (Petasites Japonicus:

[image]

They are native to Japan and are a similar scale when adult, also bearing many aesthetic similarities.